# paypal iframe custom style

Tags: css, iframe, paypal, styles

So on the website, the PayPal checkout page is implemented by using this iframe [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-plus/mexico-brazil/integrate-a-payment-selection-page/#payment-selection-page-components), where it offers the customization on css of iframe with given css key:value pairs in JSON string. you can see that [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-plus/mexico-brazil/custom-style-for-payment-wall/#example)

Now, can someone help me if I am passing the JSON string correctly, because it doesnt work for some reason. i need to make the labels white in color

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
var styles = {
    "pppLabel": {
        "color": "#fff"
    },
    "pppCheckboxLabel": {
        "color": "#fff"
    }
};

var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
    "approvalUrl": "<?=$approvalUrl?>",
    "placeholder": "ppplusDiv",
    "payerEmail": "<?=$_POST['email']?>",
    "payerFirstName": "<?=$_POST['name']?>",
    "payerLastName": "<?=$_POST['surnamename']?>",
    "payerPhone": "<?=$_POST['telephone']?>",
    "payerTaxId": "<?=$_POST['cpf']?>",
    "miniBrowser":false,
    "merchantInstallmentSelection":12,
    "merchantInstallmentSelectionOptional":true,
    "mode": "live",
    "payerTaxIdType": "BR_CPF",
    "language": "pt_BR",
    "country": "BR",
    "css": styles,
  });
```

I have made changes like

```
"css": JSON.stringify(styles)
```

but it doesnt work and give this in console

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51AwM.png)

[code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa707.png)
[web page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnziJ.png)

Comment: Can you put the code snippet as text here (in a markdown code block) instead of using screenshots? Its more developer friendly for people that may try to answer your post.

Comment: @TobeE just did. thanks

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work and show some messages in console, i am adding a screenshot as an answer to my question [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twSCx.png)

Comment: You can edit your post instead of adding to your original question from the Answers thread.